A simple question about the completness of $L^p$


Since $g<\infty$ a.e the series $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty (f_{n_{i+1}}-f_{n_i})$$ converges a.e in $X$.

From this, why also the series $$f_{n_1}+\sum_{i=1}^\infty (f_{n_{i+1}}-f_{n_i})$$ converges a.e in $X$? can it not happen that at a point $x$ where the series converges we have that $f_{n_1}(x)=\pm \infty$?

My opinion: In a point $x$ in which the series
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty (f_{n_{i+1}}(x)-f_{n_i}(x))<\infty$$
converges necessarily every terms of the series must be finite, in particular $f_{n_2}(x)-f_{n_1}(x)$ must be finite and therefore $f_{n_1}(x)$ is finite, so in every point in which the series converges we have that $f_{n_{1}}(x)$ is a number. Therefore, if we denote with $N$ the null set where the series does not converge we have that
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty (f_{n_{i+1}}-f_{n_i})<\infty\quad\text{in}\quad X\setminus N$$
and as stated before
$$f_{n_1}+\sum_{i=1}^\infty (f_{n_{i+1}}-f_{n_i})<\infty$$ in $X\setminus N$.
This is correct?

The points $x$ where $f_{n_1}(x) = \pm \infty$ are a measure zero set since $f_{n_1}$ is in $L^p(X)$.

@Chris We couldn't even say that in a point $x$ in which the series converges necessarily every terms of the series must be finite, in particular $f_{n_2}(x)-f_{n_1}(x)$ must be finite and therefore $f_{n_1}(x)$ is finite. It's correct?

Whenever you have a function in $L^{p}(X)$ which takes values in the extended real numbers, the set of elements which takes the value $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ must be contained in a set of measure zero. So if you combine such a set of measure zero with another set of measure zero outside of which $g$ takes finite values by taking their union, you have a set of measure zero where the function $f_{n_{1}} + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(f_{n_{i+1}} - f_{n_{i}})$ can be defined as a real number which coincides with the convergence of the series for all elements outside of this set of measure zero.
Your reasoning is correct as to explain another way why the expression is valid outside of a set of measure zero. However, typically what happens in practice is that you observe that you are dealing with a countable number of conditions, each of which hold outside a set of measure zero, then you can find a larger set of measure zero where all of those properties hold outside that larger set of measure zero. I would recommend making use of this process whenever it is convenient.
